# Создание роута - Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana

Решил воспользоваться возможностью HMVC для более четкого деления сайта на блоки. Продумал примерно такую структуру. В файлах вида, где нужно, я вывожу меню.

```
echo Request::factory('/blocks/menu/topmenu')->execute();
```

Где нужен сайдбар.

```
echo Request::factory('/blocks/sidebar/rightsidebar')->execute();
```

Для вывод другой информации например списка новостей тоже самое.

```
echo Request::factory('/blocks/widget/news')->execute();
```

Контроллеры располагаются в `Controller/Blocks/<тип_блока>/<имя_контроллера>`. Роут имеет соответствующий вид `Blocks/<тип_блока>/<имя_контроллера>`

Пример контроллера

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Blocks_Menu_Topmenu extends Controller {

   public function action_index()
   {   
        $content=View::factory('/blocks/menu/topmenu');
      $this->response->body($content); 
   }

} // End Menu (HMVC)
```

Как создать универсальный роут для всех их, и чтобы была проверка на то, что запрос выполнялся только внутренний, т.е пользователь не может напрямую ввести в адрес данные это роута?

Пробовал получалось громоздко и не работало, да и соображается туговато, давно с фреймворком толком не работал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можешь поступить след. образом:

bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('widget', 'widget(/<controller>(/<param>))', array(
            'param' => '.+'
        ))
        ->defaults(array(
            'directory' => 'widget',
            'action'    => 'index',
        ));
```

application/classes/Widget.php:

```
class Widget {

    protected $_route_name         = 'widget';    // Название файла конфигураций виджетов по умолчанию
    protected $_params             = array();      // Массив передаваемых параметров
    protected $_widget_name;                        // Название виждета (контроллер)

    /*
     * Вызов виджета Widget::load('widget_name', array('param' => 'val'), 'route_name');
     * @param   string  Название виджета
     * @param   array   Массив передаваемых параметров
     * @param   string  Название роута данного виджета
     */
    public static function load($widget_name, array $params = NULL, $route_name = NULL)
    {
        $widget = new Widget($widget_name, $params, $route_name);
        return $widget->render();
    }

    public function __construct($widget_name, array $params = NULL, $route_name = NULL)
    {
        if ($params != NULL)
        {
            $this->_params = $params;
        }

        if ($route_name != NULL)
        {
            $this->_route_name = $route_name;
        }

        $this->_widget_name = $widget_name;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->_params['controller'] = $this->_widget_name;
        $url = Route::get($this->_route_name)->uri($this->_params);

        return Request::factory($url)->execute();
    }

}
```

Сами виджеты кладешь в папку application/classes/Controller/Wisget/

Например:

```
class Controller_Widget_MainMenu extends Controller_Widget
{
    public $template = 'widget/mainmenu';

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template->pages = Site::Instance()->getPages();
    }
}
```

Чтоб пользователь не мог напрямую через url типа http://site.com/widget/MainMenu обратиться к виджету просто ставим условие в before:

```
class Controller_Widget extends Controller_Template
{

    public function before() {
        parent::before();

        if (Request::current()->is_initial()) {
            $this->auto_render = FALSE;
        }

    }

}
```

Я думаю ты понял, что выводить виджеты очень просто: <?= Widget::load('MainMenu') ?>

Надеюсь выручил =)

Comment: Большое спасибо ,так действительно намного проще )

Comment: Только ошибка вылезла
ErrorException [ Recoverable Error ]: Argument 2 passed to Widget::__construct() must be an array, object given 

APPPATH\classes\Widget.php [ 26 ]
21         $widget = new Widget($widget_name, $params, $route_name);

public function __construct($widget_name, array $params = NULL, $route_name = NULL)

Не могу разобраться в чем дело.

Comment: Ну читай, что написано-то) конструктор ждет массив вторым параметром. Ты передаёшь ему объект

Answer (score 0):

> Чтоб пользователь не мог напрямую через url типа http://site.com/widget/MainMenu обратиться к виджету

Эту фишку стоит либо вообще убрать, либо сделать опциональной т.к. встраивание виджетов в другие сайты очень распространено - http://www.webasyst.ru/widgets/ . Кроме того, проще сразу вызвать исключение вместо $this->auto_render = FALSE; т.к. работа action в случае внешнего вызова всё равно вызовет ошибку при $this->template->pages т.к. в $this->template будет содержаться не View объект, а строка.

Я использую вот такой метод-хэлпер для вызова контроллеров-виджетов.

```
/**
 * Wrapper for request to widget controller
 * 
 * @param   string  $uri           Request uri(widget name)
 * @param   array   $data          Send data
 * @param   string  $method        Request method
 * @param   boolean $auto_render   Execute request and return body?
 * @return  mixed
 * @uses    Request::factory
 * @uses    HTML::chars
 * @throws  Request_Exception
 */
public static function widget($uri, array $data = NULL, $method = Request::GET, $auto_render = TRUE)
{
    // Create request
    if ( ! $widget = Request::factory('widget'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$uri))
    {
        throw new Request_Exception('Request to widget :uri failed', array(':uri' => $uri));
    }
    // Set data
    switch ($method)
    {
        case Request::GET:
            $widget->query($data);
            break;
        case Request::POST:
            $widget->post($data);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Request_Exception('Unknown method :method of widget :uri', array(':method' => $method, ':uri' => $uri));
    }
    // Set data sending method
    $widget->method($method);
    // Return request body or object
    return ($auto_render ? $widget->execute()->body() : $widget);
}
```